# How to format Java ArrayList with respective rows and columns and invoke the data of a column or a row?

Tags: java, arrays, csv, arraylist

I am a Java beginner, I have been trying to read a csv file from my computer by using Java and insert the data into a ArrayList.

```
public class DataRepository {

public void loadFile(){
    ArrayList<String> binsGrade = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Max\\Desktop\\Grade_SampleData.csv"));
        while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()){

            binsGrade.add(fileScanner.nextLine());
        }

        fileScanner.close();

        System.out.println(binsGrade);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And below is the result I got:

```
[name,literature,math,physics,chemistry,biology,history,geology,art,sports, Michael,80,90,82,79,75,70,72,68,95, Amy,85,88,73,79,88,93,90,92,75, Johnson,72,89,81,84,83,72,89,90,82, Bob,80,81,84,89,87,90,71,65,89, Tommy,70,89,79,90,88,73,75,89,91, Rachel,90,91,80,92,87,92,95,97,87, Evonne,78,91,87,88,91,76,74,86,91]
```

All the records are in one row, but I actually want it to be in separated rows and columns, and for example, when I call name, I can get the value: Michael, Amy, Johson and etc. When I call literature, I can get 80, 85, 72, 80 and etc.Then I can probably use these data to do some calculation, like calculate the average, or get the maximum score and etc.

Although I have been searching online for a while, I still have not figured out the best way to achieve this. Can you please share your ideas if you have one minute? Your help will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: use Map<String,List<String>>

Comment: Choose the right data structure for your problem. What you want is a table, not a list. And use a CSV parser instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have something implemented quickly, you can follow [Srivenu comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50697852/how-to-format-java-arraylist-with-respective-rows-and-columns-and-invoke-the-dat#comment88404777_50697852) and use a `Map<String, List<String>>`. Each entry of the Map will have the name as the key, and a list of string for all the results. For example to add Michael :

```
myMap.add("Michael", Arrays.asList({"20", "12", "8", "80"}));
```

Then create the different methods that will go through this map to compute the average, or find the max, etc

---

If you want a more oriented object approach I suggest you to create objects that will represent your data. First a result object that will contain two attributes, a string that will be the subject and an int that will be the score.

```
public class Result {
    private String subject;
    private int score;

    public Result(String s, int i) {
        subject = s;
        score = i;
    }

    //Add Setters and Getters
    //Add additional method if required
}
```

Secondly Have a Person object that wil represent someone. It will have two attributes, a String representing the name and a list of Results objects.

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private List<Result> results;

    public Person(String s, List<Result> r) {
        name = s;
        results = r;
    }

    //Add getters and setters
    //Add additional methods if required

    /**
     * Example of additional method
     * This one will return the score for a given subject
    **/
    public int getScore(String subject) {
        Result r = results.get(subject);
        return r.getScore();
    }

}
```

Thirdly, create a GroupOfPerson Class that will contain one attribute, a list of person. Then This class will have methods that will return the average, the max, etc...

```
public class GroupOfPerson {
    private List<Person> persons;

    public GroupOfPErson(List<Person> p) {
        persons = p;
    }

    /**
     * Example of method.
     * This one will return the average score for the given subject
    **/
    public int getAverageForSubject(String subject) {
        int average = 0;
        for(Person p : persons) {
            average += p.getScore(subject);
        }
        average /= persons.size();
        return average;
    }

    //Add other methods
}
```

Finally when reading your CSV file, create the corresponding objects.